# Good way to prevent spamming async calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm facing a problem and think I found a working solution.
But just to be sure I would like to confront it to the public critic.

I have a small application that can fire ajax calls.

Those calls can take time to come back.

- One thing I'd hate would be to have a situation where a user that clicks multiple time sends tons of requests while results are peacefully coming back as fast as they can.
- I would also hate to know that my user (as soon as he gets wise and cures his severe generalised *clickoïdosis** case) does not get the result of the last action he called.

So in order to avoid that I've thought I could :

- tell to my function to be aware whether it's already been called and is waiting for a response.
- if it is, then it stores any other call made to it and returns doing nothing.

  - any further call will squash the stored one as I only want to keep one call (the last) alive.
- when the callback is executed, it checks if a call is pending.

  - if no call is waiting then it runs as it should
  - if a call is pending it skips it's normal behavior and just calls the method that fire the ajax call with the pending set of data clearing the variable that stores pending calls

Here is my code :

```
function bob(i) {

    var me = this;
    if (this.isFetching === undefined) {
        this.isFetching = false;
    }
    if (this.isFetching) {
        this.nextFetch = i;
        return;
    } else {
        this.isFetching = true;
    }
    yourFavoriteAjaxCallerMethod({
        url: 'http://this_server_does_not_exist.net/this.is?an=example',
        data: {
            json: JSON.encode({
                bob: i
            }),
            delay: 2
        },
        onSuccess: function (response) {
            console.log(response.bob);
            me.isFetching = false;
            if (me.nextFetch !== undefined) {
                var nextFetch = me.nextFetch;
                delete me.nextFetch;
                bob(nextFetch);
                return;
            }
            alert(response.bob);
        }
    }).send();
}
```

In order to clarify all this, I've made a working jsFiddle that should be self-explanatory enough : http://jsfiddle.net/LhermitteG/L8kqa/

So far, all works well, this is fine and dandy but my question is :

> Do I do it right ?
>
> Is there a design pattern about this ?
>
> If I did it wrong, what is bad ?
>
> How could I improve it ?
>
> Am I missing something ?
>
> You know I am ... I always miss something :(
>
> Yeah I know I have insecurities issues that I should address ...

-*  *I'm sure this is a true disease, it has to be, it's real, I've seen it !*

Comment: Easier solution: disable the clickable element until the AJAX request returns or times out.

Comment: That is a solution I thought about but which was hard to implement (for various reasons, one of which is that my function is agnostic of who might call her) in my case. But of course I could, I would favor that one first.

Comment: This question seems like a better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did not think of it, you are right.
Should I close it here and reopen it there ?

Comment: Maybe this is an elegant approach to not having too much 'spammy' traffic to the server, but it's solving a problem that wouldn't exist if you simply provided feedback to the user.  Honestly, if I click something and something doesn't happen, I get frustrated and assume something is broken.  Do what MikeW said and don't alienate your users.

Comment: You are very imperative about what I should or shouldn't do :)
What I haven't said is that there will be some kind of loading animation displayed as long as a request is pending. I just did not show it there for simplicity in explanation. Maybe I should edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the event reduction, you are talking about debouncing.  http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ has a jquery debounce method, and http://underscorejs.org/#debounce has its own implementation.

The second part of your question is typical in autocomplete - on a general search, the user first has typed fewer characters, causing a larger and typically slower response.  As they type more information, the queries are longer, but faster to respond as the search query returns fewer matches and the payload is smaller.  The software pattern that needs to insure the last most response is the Correlation Identifier pattern (163) which I believe was best presented here:  http://www.slideshare.net/kevinhakanson/implementing-messaging-patterns-in-java-script-using-the-openajax-hub - see slide 45.

If this seems too tricky, take the last request and store an associated (message) id into the callback handler either in javascript, or if you can echo it from the server, that is ideal for mapping one-to-one requests.  If any requests come back, check to see if they have the latest (message)id, if not they should be safely ignored.

Comment: You sir gave me exactly what I came for.
A clear, non judging explanation with patterns and stuff.